# How to retain javascript variables after postback of an updatepanel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, scope

after a user changes a select element which triggers a postback of an updatepanel, I'm trying to set the value of that same select to the selected value after the postback has completed, but somehow the value of the value I set in a hidden field is lost after the postback.

```
 function countrypostback() {
         $('#countryid').val($('select[name="countryselect"]').val());
         __doPostBack('upnlSearch', '');
     }

 $(document).ready(function () {
              $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/service.svc/countries/",
         data: "",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
             for (var i in msg) {
                 var resultitems = '<select onchange="countrypostback();" class="textbox" name="countryselect" id="countryselect">';
                 for (var i in msg) {
                     if (msg[i].name != '') {
                         resultitems += '<option value="' + msg[i].value + '">' + msg[i].name + '</option>';
                     }
                 }
                 resultitems += '</select>';
                 $('#countryselect').html(resultitems);
             }
         }
     });

    //here I'm trying to set the value of the dropdown to the value that was selected before the postback
     $("#countryselect").val($('#countryid').val());


    <input type="hidden" id="countryid" name="countryid" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlSearch" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>  


<span id="countryselect"></span>

</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried placing the hidden field countryid both outside and inside the updatepanel, but that does not make a difference, I still have an empty formfield when I try to access it via

```
$('#countryid').val()
```

I'd rather not work with viewstate (if at all possible) since that increase that pageload.

Comment: ugh asp.net nightmare, i hated update panels and uninstalled visual studio and their other crappy "tools". The reason is simply because its causing a postback you can't keep track of the value unless its saved in a cookie or session. not sure how to override update panels or if you can, what i would do is get rid of Microsoft's shitty ajax implementation and create your own using jQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

May you can access the hiddenfield on serverside (runat server) and there you can make sure that it is written in the page again. Otherwise you have some possibilities to store it clientside but none of them are that pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Without the postback it would be as simple as this, you can probably prevent the postback using event.preventDefault() as well. Problem i found with Microsoft's update panels is server-side code always executes before client-side code so it's hard or close to impossible to prevent the default actions. Always thought that was dumb and their unique ids which totally make it impossible to select anything with jQuery.

```
$('select').on('change', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NtzRC/1/

Comment: Ok, but using the default postback allows me to easily execute server side code. If I would go with jQuery: do you have a sample, if even possible, to call a non-webservice server side method and get the return value as an integer?
The function signature: Private Function ShowSearchResults(byval country as integer, byval province as integer, byval rooms as integer) as Integer. The function actually has more parameters, but you get the idea.

Comment: you can handle how the pages display ids using **ClientIDMode** setting in .net 4.0, or just use something like **Ctype(fvData.findControl("mycontrol")).ClientID**

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you there.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // execute script once
    [javascript code]
    // register script with PageRequestManager for partialpostback "reset value of control"
    if(typeof(Sys)!=='undefined'){
    if(typeof(Sys.WebForms)!=='undefined'){
    if(typeof(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager)!=='undefined'){
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function(){
    [javascript code]
    });
    }
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The e.preventDefault(); is the ideal solution especially when working with JQuery and 
Ajax. Below is an example of a button click event which does error handling in JQuery
using ASP.NET required fields then posts an array to a web service on the .aspx page 
which returns a value to be saved in a hiddenfield control.  Once the web service 
returns the value to be stored in the hidden field, the complete function displays the 
success message in a label based on the boolean value assigned from the success 
function.  Here is my example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#<%=btnApply.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
  var formtitle = $("#<%=txtFormTitle.ClientID %>");
  var email = $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>");
  var tdform = $("#trform .tdform");
  var formId = $("#<%=hdnFormTemplateID.ClientID %>");
  var statuslabel = $("#<%=lblStatus.ClientID %>");
  var successful = false;
  statuslabel.html("");

      if (!formtitle.val() || !email.val()) {
      statuslabel.css("color", "#CC3300");
      statuslabel.html("The following fields are invalid!");
      return false;
      }
  else {
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FormBuilder.aspx/GetFormElements",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ columnone: firstColumn, columntwo: secondColumn, title: formtitle.val(), emailaddress: email.val(), form: tdform.html(), formId: formId.val() }),
    success: function (data) {
      var id = $("#<%=hdnFormTemplateID.ClientID %>")
      id.val(data.d);
      successful = true;
    },
    error: function (err) {
      err = "Did not work";
      alert(err);
    },
    complete: function () {
       if (successful) {
         var statuslabel = $("#<%=lblStatus.ClientID %>");
                 statuslabel.html("");                                       
         statuslabel.css("color", "#92aa6c");
         statuslabel.html("Successfully Updated");

    }
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
  }
});
});
Here is the web service sub procedure.  I always find it helpful to have someone post 
VB.NET code and I will do so more in the future for those who prefer to work in 
VB.NET.
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

<ScriptService()>
Public Class FormBuilder
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Public Shared formTemplateId As Integer


<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetFormElements(columnone As List(Of String), columntwo As 
  List(Of String), title As String, emailaddress As String, form As String, formId As 
  String) As String 
  Dim strconn As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
  Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strconn)
  Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand
  Dim retVal As Integer = 0
  Dim itemOne As String = String.Empty

  'mylogic to begin storing the data in the database using a For Loop'
  If columnone.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To columnone.Count - 1 Step 1
        itemOne = Regex.Replace(columnone(i).ToString, "\s", "")
    Next
  End If


  Return retVal.ToString

 End Function
```

End Class